# Compound Poisson Distribution with Sum of Poisson Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I am trying to find the distribution of a compound Poisson distribution with sum of Poisson random variables.

Suppose that $N \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_1)$,

and that $X_1, X_2, ...$ are i.i.d. r.v.s. that are again $\sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_2)$.

What is the distribution of $Y = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N}X_n$ ?

Is there any analytic solution for this distribution?

Any kind of help is thanked in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic function is derived [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1707557/a-sum-of-a-random-number-of-poisson-random-variables).
$$\exp(\lambda_1 ( \exp(\lambda_2 (e^{it}-1))-1))$$
You could differentiate this to find the mean, variance, and other moments- see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Moments).
Mean is $\lambda_1 \lambda_2$, variance is $\lambda_1 \lambda_2(\lambda_2 +1)$.